# With or without FOR? "The last thing I want is (FOR) anyone to..."

Tags: phrases, expressions, prepositions

I am doing Proficiency exam practice and came across the following sentence transformation:[image]

As you can see, according to the answer key, my answer is wrong. However, I did [some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22last%20thing%20I%20want%20is%20anyone%20to%22&sxsrf=ALeKk00gvY7Y1x1atbeVBlsDoDMOevutwg%3A1617956422038&ei=Rg5wYNXzAfGBi-gPvK2SgA8&oq=%22last%20thing%20I%20want%20is%20anyone%20to%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BQgAELADOgcIABCwAxAeOgsILhCwAxDIAxCTAjoICC4QsAMQyAM6CAgAEAgQBxAeSgUIOBIBMVCBHljygQFg9oIBaAFwAHgBgAHsAYgB0xOSAQY0LjE3LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEMwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjVrrCu3fDvAhXxwAIHHbyWBPAQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) and found out that my version also works. Is it the case of the structure simply being more idiomatic with **FOR**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your answer is plain wrong.

It would be correct to say “I don’t want anyone to intervene”.
But in your example the clause “anyone to intervene” is a predicate to “thing”, not a complement to “want”.

Try slightly changing the word order:
“For anyone to intervene is the last thing I want” is correct.
“Anyone to intervene is the last thing I want” is obviously incorrect.

Comment: NB There is an unwanted 'to' in the question title.

Comment: Yes, this was my bad - fixed the title now.